# dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved

Tags: android, dagger-2, multi-module

I've been trying to setup dagger in a multimodule project. My setup is the following:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, NetworkModule::class, MovieListActivityModule::class, DetailActivityModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MoviesApplication)
}

@Module
class NetworkModule { .... }

@Module
abstract class MovieListActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ListFragmentModule::class, ListNetworkModule::class, ListViewModelsModule::class])
    abstract fun bindMovieListActivity(): MovieListActivity
    }

@Module
abstract class ListFragmentModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindListFragment(): ListFragment
}

@Module
public class ListNetworkModule {

    @Provides
    SearchService providesSearchService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(SearchService.class);
    }
}

@Module
abstract class ListViewModelsModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindDaggerViewModelFactory(daggerViewModelFactory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ListViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindListViewModel(listViewModel: ListViewModel): ViewModel
}

@Module
abstract class DetailActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [DetailViewModelsModule::class, DetailNetworkModule::class, DbModule::class])
    abstract fun bindDetailActivity(): DetailActivity
}

@Module
abstract class DetailViewModelsModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindDaggerViewModelFactory(daggerViewModelFactory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(DetailsViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindDetailViewModel(detailsViewModel: DetailsViewModel): ViewModel
}

@Module
public class DetailNetworkModule {

    @Provides
    DetailService providesDetailService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(DetailService.class);
    }
}

@Module
class DbModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesFavouriteMovieDb(application: Application): FavMovieDb = FavMovieDb.getDatabase(application)
}

class DaggerViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>)
    : ViewModelProvider.Factory {.........}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)

class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingActivityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>? = dispatchingActivityInjector
}
```

Till this code everything was ok and works perfectly. But problem appears when I add a new `FavouriteActivityModule` in `AppComponent`. Like below:

```
@Module
abstract class FavouriteViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindDaggerViewModelFactory(daggerViewModelFactory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(FavouriteViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindFavouriteViewModel(viewModel: FavouriteViewModel): ViewModel
}

@Module
abstract class FavouriteActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FavouriteViewModelModule::class, DbModule::class])
    abstract fun bindFavouriteActivity(): FavoriteActivity
}
```

Final AppComponent looks like this (added `FavouriteActivityModule::class`):

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, NetworkModule::class, MovieListActivityModule::class, DetailActivityModule::class, FavouriteActivityModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MoviesApplication)
}
```

After adding `FavouriteActivityModule::class` dagger is no more building and complaining like below:

```
e: /Users/...../di/AppComponent.java:8: error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
            ^
```

I've not figured out the reason yet and already spent whole day finding out the reason of this error. Any help? TIA

Comment: FYI, using dagger `2.16` and kotlin `1.2.60`